# What is the purpose of the "host" blob in azure-webjobs-hosts storage container with Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I have an Azure Function App with Python functions that have Service Bus trigger enabled. I noticed that within the storage account associated with the Function App, there is a storage container named `azure-webjobs-hosts`, that has a folder named `locks` in it. It has several folders inside named exactly like my Function App (or my App Service plan, not sure, because they are named the same), and each of them has a `hosts` file inside. My function apps are scaled out to multiple instances. Whenever I check the `hosts` file for one of my Function Apps, the metadata of the blob always contains a single entry, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYzHb.png). I've spent countless hours trying to understand what happens under the hood, as I have multiple instances running, but there is only a single "FunctionInstance" leasing this blob. Does this affect other instances in processing my Service Bus queue messages? Why is this blob leased by only one of the instances all the time? (If I restart the Function App, it might get leased by another instance ID after restart, so I guess it is typically the ID of one of the instances for that Function App, but it does stay leased by a single instance according to the metadata) Even if I am not affected here, could you provide an example where this `hosts` file is used by Azure Functions, and why it starts by trying to lock on startup?

I started to experiment locally to better understand what is happening. What I found is the following:
The first function that I start (with `func start`) makes a HEAD request to this blob, then makes a PUT request to this blob with `comp=lease` URL parameter, then another HEAD request, and finally after another PUT request with `comp=metadata` URL parameter I get the following log line: `Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000711A638F'.` After this, it starts to process my Service Bus messages from the queue.
The second function that I start on this machine however, never gets the `Host lock lease acquired by instance ID 'xxx'.` message, it periodically sends a HEAD request to this blob, and seems like it never acquires the blob for lease. However, this second function is also triggered by the messages in the queue and processes them as intended just like the first one.

Please explain the logic behind the leasable hosts file.
(PS: I have my Function App scaled to 3 instances and I have Azure Functions Premium Plan)

Answer (score 0):

- The host lock lease files are kept in the azure-webjobs-hosts container in the storage account linked to your Function App.
- These files are needed to make sure that your Function App is only processing messages from the Service Bus queue in one instance at a time. A Function App instance tries to obtain a lease on the host lock file upon startup. It begins analyzing messages from the queue if it is successful. If it doesn't work, it checks the status of the lease on a regular basis and begins processing messages as soon at the lease becomes available.
- Within the azure-webjobs-hosts container, the locks folder has folders named for each Function App instance. A hosts file tha has the instance's lease information is present in every folder. Because only one instance of your Function App can hold the lease at once, the blob's metadata always has one entry.
- Azure Functions implements the singleton behavior for your Function App using the locks folder. Only one instance of your Function App will be processing messages from the Service Bus queue at a time because of the singleton behavior.
- The host ID collision detection feature is also implemented using the locks folder. The Functions runtime 3.x version onwards detects host ID collision and logs a warning. Version 4.x causes a hard failure by logging an error and stopping the host. You may get more information on host ID collision  [**here**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/storage-considerations.md#avoiding-host-id-collisions)

[image]

[image]

According to this [Blog](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/03/14/azure-webjob-logs-demystified/#):-

The ***azure-webjobs-host*** container, in turn, hosts three folders:-

- Heartbeats - Contains a 0-byte log of every heartbeat check performed on the service.
- Ids - Contains a single blog directory with a unique identifier for this service.
- Output Logs - Hosts the output of verbose logs for each run. Explicit logs are logs added to the runtime code by the WebJob developers.

Comment: After carefully reading through your points, I still don't understand the following: You've mentioned that "the locks folder has folders named for each Function App instance". In my case, I have a Function App named `prod-interpreter`, and the app service plan associated with it is also called `prod-interpreter`. I only have 1 folder in the locks folder named `prod-interpreter`, even though the App Service Plan is scaled out to 3 instances. My feeling is that you are referring to the App Service Plan as the "instance" rather than the physical (3) instances of the App Service Plan. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to App service Plan as an instance.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Could you please tell me why does this make sense at all? Since it is not possible to create two App Service Plans with the same name, the folders in the locks folder will all have different names, and will have their own `host` file to lease. This means that if I create two Function Apps with two App Service plans that process messages from the same Service Bus queue, they will be able to do it in parallel, since the instances will lease different `host` files. One Function App on the other hand will always have one App Service Plan, so only that can read the queue.

Comment: @AndrásCzinege According to the documentation, the azure-webjobs-host container hosts three folders: Heartbeats, Ids, and Output Logs[[storage-consideration]](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/storage-considerations.md). The locks folder has folders named for each Function App instance. In your case, you have a Function App named prod-interpreter, and the app service plan associated with it is also called prod-interpreter. You only have one folder in the locks folder.